# What's the difference between usePreloadedQuery and useQueryLoader?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-relay

I'm learning graphQL and react-relay library.

In these 2 sections:

1. [Rendering Queries](https://relay.dev/docs/guided-tour/rendering/queries/#rendering-queries): introduce `usePreloadedQuery`.
2. [Fetching Queries for Render](https://relay.dev/docs/guided-tour/rendering/queries/#fetching-queries-for-render): introduce `useQueryLoader`.

For short, I will say `1st-query` instead of `usePreloadedQuery`, `2nd-query` for `useQueryLoader`.

##### Question-1

The `1st-query` will use a graphQL and it's generated flow type, query the server, then return the data. That's OK to me.

The `2nd-query` seems to do the same thing? What's the difference except the library API/syntax?

##### Question-2

Here's the sample code in the 2nd section:

```js
import type {HomeTabQuery as HomeTabQueryType} from 'HomeTabQuery.graphql';
import type {PreloadedQuery} from 'react-relay';

const HomeTabQuery = require('HomeTabQuery.graphql')
const {useQueryLoader} = require('react-relay');


type Props = {
  initialQueryRef: PreloadedQuery<HomeTabQueryType>,
};

function AppTabs(props) {
  const [
    homeTabQueryRef,
    loadHomeTabQuery,
  ] = useQueryLoader<HomeTabQueryType>(
    HomeTabQuery,
    props.initialQueryRef, /* e.g. provided by router */
  );

  const onSelectHomeTab = () => {
    // Start loading query for HomeTab immediately in the event handler
    // that triggers navigation to that tab, *before* we even start
    // rendering the target tab.
    // Calling this function will update the value of homeTabQueryRef.
    loadHomeTabQuery({id: '4'});

    // ...
  }

  // ...

  return (
    screen === 'HomeTab' && homeTabQueryRef != null ?
      // Pass to component that uses usePreloadedQuery
      <HomeTab queryRef={homeTabQueryRef} /> :
      // ...
  );
}
```

The line-1 use `import type {HomeTabQuery as HomeTabQueryType} from 'HomeTabQuery.graphql'`. And the line-4 use `const HomeTabQuery = require('HomeTabQuery.graphql')`.

I don't understand, aren't these 2 lines do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

I guess one of the obvious differences is you can use `useQueryLoader` for loading your query on demand. On the other hand, you can you use `usePreloadedQuery` for situations like render as you fetch.